# Algorithm for Deep Hash Invert (should be in ruby)

Tags: ruby, algorithm, hash

I have a hash `H` (see bottom) and need to perform a deep invert operation on it, such that a new hash `H2` is returned where each key `K` is a value inside the original hash. The keys in `H2` map to an array of arrays of all the sequences of keys that, when applied onto the original hash `H` would give you the key `K` which is a value in the original hash.

Perhaps I should use a different data structure for the output, such as a hash of hashes?

I'd like this to work with hashes of arbitrary nesting levels.

I don't know where to start designing an optimal algorithm

### Original Hash

What the input might look like

```
{
  u: {
    u: { u: :phe, c: :phe, a: :leu, g: :leu },
    c: { u: :ser, c: :ser, a: :ser, g: :ser },
    a: { u: :tyr, c: :tyr, a: :STOP, g: :STOP },
    g: { u: :cys, c: :cys, a: :STOP, g: :trp }
  },
  c: {
    u: { u: :leu, c: :leu, a: :leu, g: :leu },
    c: { u: :pro, c: :pro, a: :pro, g: :pro },
    a: { u: :his, c: :his, a: :gln, g: :gln },
    g: { u: :arg, c: :arg, a: :arg, g: :arg }
  },
  {...}
}
```

### Simplified Output

What output would look like

```
{
  phe: [[:u,:u,:u],[:u,:u,:c]],
  leu: [[:u,:u,:a],[:u,:u,:g]],
  ser: [[:u,:c,:u],[:u,:c,:c],[:u,:u,:a],[:u,:u,:g]],
  tyr: [[:u,:a,:u],[:u,:a,:c]],
  "...": [[...]]
}
```

**Why? I'm writing my own bioinformatics library and want to be able to return the possible nucleotide sequences for a given protein, denoted by the three character `:symbols`**

Comment: I don't understand your description. Where do `:val` and `:ala` come from and why does the output hash contain strings?

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: are you just looking for `[:val,:ala].zip(h.map {|k,v| [k.to_s].product(v.keys.map(&:to_s))}).to_h` ? That should do it for your example but I have no idea what the application for this would be that's why I won't make this an actual answer. Also when someone says ***"deep"*** I don't generally think one level which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for editing, it makes sense now.

Comment: This looks fun! One direction you could go is a [depth first tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first).

Comment: Is there a chance to change the structure of the *input* hash? Using arrays as keys would make it much easier: `{ [:u, :u, :u] => :phe, [:u, :u, :c] => :phe, [:u, :u, :a] => :leu, ... }`

Comment: I already have the data in the given format. Reformatting it would beat the point of designing an algorithm to do the work.

Comment: My output differs from yours for the key `:leu`. Could you please check that? It's an interesting question, but in future please: 1) pare the examples  down to the minimum (e.g., it would have been sufficient for the inner-most hashes to have just two elements); 2) no `...` and 3) when you give input data include a name (e.g., `H = { ... }`, so that those giving solutions need not define it. (Yes, you did say it was `H`, but better to just  write `H =...`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code**

```
def recurse(h, arr=[])
  h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g.update((Hash===v) ?
    recurse(v, arr + [k]) : { v=>[arr+[k]] }) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
end
```

The recursion uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs the block `{ |_,o,n| o+n } }` to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

**Example 1**

```
h =
{
  u: {
    u: { u: :phe, c: :phe, a: :leu, g: :leu },
    c: { u: :ser, c: :ser, a: :ser, g: :ser },
    a: { u: :tyr, c: :tyr, a: :STOP, g: :STOP },
    g: { u: :cys, c: :cys, a: :STOP, g: :trp }
  },
  c: {
    u: { u: :leu, c: :leu, a: :leu, g: :leu },
    c: { u: :pro, c: :pro, a: :pro, g: :pro },
    a: { u: :his, c: :his, a: :gln, g: :gln },
    g: { u: :arg, c: :arg, a: :arg, g: :arg }
  },
}

recurse h
  #=> {:phe=>[[:u, :u, :u], [:u, :u, :c]],
  #    :leu=>[[:u, :u, :a], [:u, :u, :g], [:c, :u, :u],
  #      [:c, :u, :c], [:c, :u, :a], [:c, :u, :g]],
  #    :ser=>[[:u, :c, :u], [:u, :c, :c], [:u, :c, :a], [:u, :c, :g]], 
  #    :tyr=>[[:u, :a, :u], [:u, :a, :c]],
  #    :STOP=>[[:u, :a, :a], [:u, :a, :g], [:u, :g, :a]],
  #    :cys=>[[:u, :g, :u], [:u, :g, :c]],
  #    :trp=>[[:u, :g, :g]],
  #    :pro=>[[:c, :c, :u], [:c, :c, :c], [:c, :c, :a], [:c, :c, :g]], 
  #    :his=>[[:c, :a, :u], [:c, :a, :c]],
  #    :gln=>[[:c, :a, :a], [:c, :a, :g]],
  #    :arg=>[[:c, :g, :u], [:c, :g, :c], [:c, :g, :a], [:c, :g, :g]]}
```

**Example 2**

```
h =
{
  u: {
    u: { u: :phe, a: :leu },
    c: { u: :ser, c: :phe },
    a: { u: :tyr, c: { a: { u: :leu, c: :ser }, u: :tyr } }
  },
  c: {
    u: { u: :leu, c: :pro },
    a: { u: :arg }
  },
}

recurse(h)
  #=> {:phe=>[[:u, :u, :u], [:u, :c, :c]],
  #    :leu=>[[:u, :u, :a], [:u, :a, :c, :a, :u], [:c, :u, :u]],
  #    :ser=>[[:u, :c, :u], [:u, :a, :c, :a, :c]],
  #    :tyr=>[[:u, :a, :u], [:u, :a, :c, :u]],
  #    :pro=>[[:c, :u, :c]], :arg=>[[:c, :a, :u]]}
```

**Explanation**

Here is the code modified to display the calculations that are being performed:

```
def recurse(h, arr=[], level = 0)
  indent = ' '*(2*level)
  puts "#{indent}level = #{level}"
  puts "#{indent}h= #{h}"
  puts "#{indent}arr= #{arr}"
  g = h.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),g|
    puts "#{indent}  level = #{level}"
    puts "#{indent}  k=#{k}"
    puts "#{indent}  v=#{v}"
    puts "#{indent}  g=#{g}"
    case v
    when Hash
      puts "#{indent}  v is Hash"
      g.update(recurse(v, arr + [k], level+1)) { |_,o,n| o+n }
    else
      puts "#{indent}  v is not a Hash"
      g.update({ v=>[arr+[k]] }) { |_,o,n| o+n }
    end
  end
  puts "#{indent}return #{g}"
  g
end
```

The output for `recurse h` follows, for Example 2 (for diehards only).

```
level = 0
h= {:u=>{:u=>{:u=>:phe, :a=>:leu}, :c=>{:u=>:ser, :c=>:phe}, :a=>{:u=>:tyr, :c=>{:a=>{:u=>:leu, :c=>:ser}, :u=>:tyr}}}, :c=>{:u=>{:u=>:leu, :c=>:pro}, :a=>{:u=>:arg}}}
arr= []
  level = 0
  k=u
  v={:u=>{:u=>:phe, :a=>:leu}, :c=>{:u=>:ser, :c=>:phe},
     :a=>{:u=>:tyr, :c=>{:a=>{:u=>:leu, :c=>:ser}, :u=>:tyr}}}
  g={}
  v is Hash
  level = 1
  h= {:u=>{:u=>:phe, :a=>:leu}, :c=>{:u=>:ser, :c=>:phe},
      :a=>{:u=>:tyr, :c=>{:a=>{:u=>:leu, :c=>:ser}, :u=>:tyr}}}
  arr= [:u]
    level = 1
    k=u
    v={:u=>:phe, :a=>:leu}
    g={}
    v is Hash
    level = 2
    h= {:u=>:phe, :a=>:leu}
    arr= [:u, :u]
      level = 2
      k=u
      v=phe
      g={}
      v is not a Hash
      level = 2
      k=a
      v=leu
      g={:phe=>[[:u, :u, :u]]}
      v is not a Hash
    return {:phe=>[[:u, :u, :u]], :leu=>[[:u, :u, :a]]}
    level = 1
    k=c
    v={:u=>:ser, :c=>:phe}
    g={:phe=>[[:u, :u, :u]], :leu=>[[:u, :u, :a]]}
    v is Hash
    level = 2
    h= {:u=>:ser, :c=>:phe}
    arr= [:u, :c]
      level = 2
      k=u
      v=ser
      g={}
      v is not a Hash
      level = 2
      k=c
      v=phe
      g={:ser=>[[:u, :c, :u]]}
      v is not a Hash
    return {:ser=>[[:u, :c, :u]], :phe=>[[:u, :c, :c]]}
    level = 1
    k=a
    v={:u=>:tyr, :c=>{:a=>{:u=>:leu, :c=>:ser}, :u=>:tyr}}
    g={:phe=>[[:u, :u, :u], [:u, :c, :c]], :leu=>[[:u, :u, :a]], :ser=>[[:u, :c, :u]]}
    v is Hash
    level = 2
    h= {:u=>:tyr, :c=>{:a=>{:u=>:leu, :c=>:ser}, :u=>:tyr}}
    arr= [:u, :a]
      level = 2
      k=u
      v=tyr
      g={}
      v is not a Hash
      level = 2
      k=c
      v={:a=>{:u=>:leu, :c=>:ser}, :u=>:tyr}
      g={:tyr=>[[:u, :a, :u]]}
      v is Hash
      level = 3
      h= {:a=>{:u=>:leu, :c=>:ser}, :u=>:tyr}
      arr= [:u, :a, :c]
        level = 3
        k=a
        v={:u=>:leu, :c=>:ser}
        g={}
        v is Hash
        level = 4
        h= {:u=>:leu, :c=>:ser}
        arr= [:u, :a, :c, :a]
          level = 4
          k=u
          v=leu
          g={}
          v is not a Hash
          level = 4
          k=c
          v=ser
          g={:leu=>[[:u, :a, :c, :a, :u]]}
          v is not a Hash
        return {:leu=>[[:u, :a, :c, :a, :u]], :ser=>[[:u, :a, :c, :a, :c]]}
        level = 3
        k=u
        v=tyr
        g={:leu=>[[:u, :a, :c, :a, :u]], :ser=>[[:u, :a, :c, :a, :c]]}
        v is not a Hash
      return {:leu=>[[:u, :a, :c, :a, :u]], :ser=>[[:u, :a, :c, :a, :c]],
              :tyr=>[[:u, :a, :c, :u]]}
    return {:tyr=>[[:u, :a, :u], [:u, :a, :c, :u]], :leu=>[[:u, :a, :c, :a, :u]],
            :ser=>[[:u, :a, :c, :a, :c]]}
  return {:phe=>[[:u, :u, :u], [:u, :c, :c]], :leu=>[[:u, :u, :a], [:u, :a, :c, :a, :u]],
          :ser=>[[:u, :c, :u], [:u, :a, :c, :a, :c]], :tyr=>[[:u, :a, :u], [:u, :a, :c, :u]]}
  level = 0
  k=c
  v={:u=>{:u=>:leu, :c=>:pro}, :a=>{:u=>:arg}}
  g={:phe=>[[:u, :u, :u], [:u, :c, :c]], :leu=>[[:u, :u, :a], [:u, :a, :c, :a, :u]],
     :ser=>[[:u, :c, :u], [:u, :a, :c, :a, :c]], :tyr=>[[:u, :a, :u], [:u, :a, :c, :u]]}
  v is Hash
  level = 1
  h= {:u=>{:u=>:leu, :c=>:pro}, :a=>{:u=>:arg}}
  arr= [:c]
    level = 1
    k=u
    v={:u=>:leu, :c=>:pro}
    g={}
    v is Hash
    level = 2
    h= {:u=>:leu, :c=>:pro}
    arr= [:c, :u]
      level = 2
      k=u
      v=leu
      g={}
      v is not a Hash
      level = 2
      k=c
      v=pro
      g={:leu=>[[:c, :u, :u]]}
      v is not a Hash
    return {:leu=>[[:c, :u, :u]], :pro=>[[:c, :u, :c]]}
    level = 1
    k=a
    v={:u=>:arg}
    g={:leu=>[[:c, :u, :u]], :pro=>[[:c, :u, :c]]}
    v is Hash
    level = 2
    h= {:u=>:arg}
    arr= [:c, :a]
      level = 2
      k=u
      v=arg
      g={}
      v is not a Hash
    return {:arg=>[[:c, :a, :u]]}
  return {:leu=>[[:c, :u, :u]], :pro=>[[:c, :u, :c]], :arg=>[[:c, :a, :u]]}
return {:phe=>[[:u, :u, :u], [:u, :c, :c]],
        :leu=>[[:u, :u, :a], [:u, :a, :c, :a, :u], [:c, :u, :u]],
        :ser=>[[:u, :c, :u], [:u, :a, :c, :a, :c]],
        :tyr=>[[:u, :a, :u], [:u, :a, :c, :u]],
        :pro=>[[:c, :u, :c]],
        :arg=>[[:c, :a, :u]]}
  #=> <the last value returned above>
```